# Lagrange multipliers with trigonometric functions. Stucked figuring out x and y values.

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I want to find the maximum of the function $f(x,y) = \cos^2(x) + \cos^2(y)$ with the constraint $x-y = \pi/4$.

Here are my partial derivatives:

$$f_x = -2\cos(x)\cdot\sin(x)$$
$$f_y = -2\cos(y)\cdot\sin(y)$$
$$g_x = 1$$
$$g_y = -1$$

I have the following system of equations:
\begin{align*}
-2\cos(x)\cdot\sin(x) = \lambda\\
-2\cos(y)\cdot\sin(y) = -\lambda\\
x-y = \pi/4
\end{align*}

And from this I got from 1 and 2 equation the equality:

$-2\cos(x)\cdot\sin(x) = 2\cos(y)\cdot\sin(y)$

and we can simplify this to: $\sin(2x) = -\sin(2y)$

And what should I do next in order to find maximum of this function?
Also checked by Wolframa, that global maximum doesn't exist. Only global maximums. How can I check the existence of global maximum and minimum in such cases?

Comment: To test for global extrema, you look at all critical points (points that satisfy your Lagrange equations--not sure if that's the correct terminology).  Then you must test all points on the boundary--but since this constraint is unbounded (I believe) you only need to test each critical point.  I suspect you can show that a certain set of critical points give local maxima and another set give local minima, something like $f(x,y) = max$ for $x = y = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n$ (btw, that is _definitely_ incorrect since $x = y$ doesn't fit your constraint).

Comment: Also, I think there are some typos and mistakes.  I assume your first equation should be $-2\cos(x)\sin(x) = \lambda$ (not $=4\lambda x$) and $-2\cos(x)\sin(x) = -2\sin(2x)$ so you should have that $\sin(2x) = -\sin(2y)$ or $\sin(2x) = \sin(-2y)$.

Comment: Now you can substitute $x=y+\frac{\pi}{4}$ and simplify $\sin 2x$

Answer (score 5):

Why use Lagrange multipliers for this problem? Putting $x=y+\frac{\pi}{4}$, we have essentially a function of single variable $$\cos(y+\pi/4)^2+\cos^2y=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos(2y+\frac{\pi}{4})$$ which has maximum value $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and minimum value $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first off, I believe you should end up with:

$$
\sin(2x) = -\sin(2y) \\
\sin(2x) = \sin(-2y)
$$

You need to be very careful with sine because it's not simply true that $2x = -2y \rightarrow y = -x$.  First off, the sines are equal not only when the two arguments are equal but *also* when they differ by $2\pi n$, so we would really have: $2x = -2y+2\pi n \rightarrow y = -x +\pi n$.  To further complicate things, over the range of $2\pi$, other than for $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, the sine will always have two distinct angles where it is equal.

Let's assume that an angle $\theta$ is in the first quadrant, then $\sin(\theta) = \sin(\pi - \theta)$ (this can be verified via the unit circle).  It can then also be verified to work if $\theta$ is in the second quadrant (it will just give us back the first quadrant angle).  Finally you can verify that it *also* works for angles in the third and fourth quadrants.  If you want to be certain, you can always use the angle addition formula:

\begin{align}
\sin(\pi-\theta) =&\ \cos(\pi)\sin(-\theta) + \cos(\theta)\sin(\pi) \\
=&\ -\sin(-\theta) \\
=&\ \sin(\theta)
\end{align}

Therefore we *actually* have that:

$$
2x = -2y + 2\pi n \rightarrow y = -x + \pi n\\
2x + 2\pi m = \pi + 2y \rightarrow y = x - \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi m
$$

(I chose the side to put the $+2\pi n$ on so that it stayed positive although that's not necessary since $m$,$n$ can also be negatives)

These need to be plugged into your constraint equation:

$$
x - y = x + x - \pi n = \frac{\pi}{4}\\
x = \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2} 
$$

and

$$
x - y = \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi m = \frac{\pi}{4} \\
m = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \notin \mathbb{Z}
$$

It's good that the second set had no solutions (for the constraint equation) since the $x$'s dropped out.  If we *had* found an integer $m$ then there would have been an infinite number of solutions (i.e *any* value of $x$ would have been a critical point).

Finally let's find $y$ given $x$:

\begin{align}
y =&\ x - \frac{\pi}{4} \\
=&\ \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\\
=&\ -\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2}
\end{align}

Plug into your original function (but first I'm going to use the following):

$$
\cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1 + \cos(2\theta)}{2}
$$

So we have:

\begin{align}
f(x^*, y^*) =&\ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(2\left(\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\right) + \cos\left(2\left(-\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\right)\right) \\
=&\ 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n\right) + \cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n\right)\right) \\
=&\ 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos(\pi n) + \cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos(\pi n)\right) \\
=&\ 1 + \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)(-1)^{n}
\end{align}

(note that $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^{n}$--again, look at your unit circle)

This now gives your maxima and minima:

$$
f(x^*, y^*) = \begin{cases}
1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & n \text{ even} \\
1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

**Finding critical points without Lagrange Multipliers**

This answer can be *further* verified because this particular problem doesn't really "require" Lagrange Multipliers since the constraint equation is so simple:

$$
y = x - \frac{\pi}{4}
$$

You can then plug that into your function $f(x,y)$ to obtain a function of a single variable:

\begin{align}
g(x) =&\ 1 + \frac{\cos(2x) + \cos\left(2\left(x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)}{2}\\
=&\ 1 + \frac{\cos(2x) + \cos\left(2x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{2} \\
=&\ 1 + \frac{\cos(2x) + \cos(2x)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \sin(2x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{2} \\
=&\ 1 + \frac{\cos(2x) + \sin(2x)}{2}
\end{align}

(since $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0$ and $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1$)

Now find the critical points by setting the derivative to zero:

$$
g'(x) = -\sin(2x) + \cos(2x)
$$

Find $g'(x) = 0$:

$$
\sin(2x) - \cos(2x) = 0 \\
\cos(2x)\left(\tan(2x) - 1\right) = 0 \\
\tan(2x) = 1
$$

(we don't need to worry about $\cos(2x) = 0$ in the above since we can only factor out if $\cos(2x) \neq 0$)

Finally we know that $\tan(X) = 1$ when $X = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n$ therefore we have:

$$
2x = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n \\
x = \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2}
$$

Since this is *exactly* what we got for the critical points of $x$ above, the steps would now be the same to find the maxima and minima (i.e. plug into the original function).